# Erro Fatal ao Conectar ao Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou recebendo um erro ao conectar ao database

Codigo Php:

```html
<?php
 $siteA = 'http://www.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
 $siteB = '/';
 $email_suporte_staff = 'suporte@cinepophd.com';

 global $siteB;
 global $siteA;

 $config_bd = array(
  'host' => 'meuhost',
  'db' => 'database',
  'usuario' => 'databaseuser',
  'senha' => 'password',
 );
    error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
 $conect = mysql_connect($config_bd['host'], $config_bd['usuario'], $config_bd['senha']);
 if($conect)
 {
  mysql_select_db($config_bd['db']);
  mysql_set_charset('utf8');
 }
 else
 {
  echo '<center><b>config/config.php</b> nao configurado.</center>';
  exit;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta a mensagem do erro. E já comece a estudar as funções `mysqli` ou PDO. As funções `mysql` já estão obsoletas e foram removidas do PHP 7.

Comment: vlw quando você mencionou sobre o Php 7 Lembrei que o  Script foi feito no 5 ai Instalei ele e Funcionou